# How to define the sequence of discontinuity points for integrate.quad method

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I have an integrand similar to Dirac Delta Function. But it is finite and with a very narrow base.
I need to integrate it, but quad method has not recognized this singularity.

After looking in python docs:

> **points** : (sequence of floats,ints), optional. A sequence of break
>   points in the bounded integration interval where local difficulties of
>   the integrand may occur (e.g., singularities, discontinuities). The
>   sequence does not have to be sorted.

I am trying to define the point where the singularity is, without success.

```
integral, err = sp.integrate.quad(integrand, 0, LIM,points=[maxX,maxY])
```

Getting:

```
ValueError: The input is invalid.
```

How to define this point???

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I assume `sp` is `scipy`? That's not part of the Python standard library, so you should really add an appropriate tag, so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get that error is if either `maxX` or `maxY` is outside the range `[0, LIM]`.   The name of `maxY` is suspicious.  The values in `points` should be values in the interval of integration (i.e. `x` values, not `y` values).  If in fact `maxY` is the function value at `maxX`, then use just `points=[maxX]`.